# Cannot sort by Events in Mac Photos

Tags: mac

My photos are no longer organized by Events in the new Mac Photos. How do I search the new Mac Photos by events?

Answer (score 1):

Upon conversion your iPhoto events have been transformed into Albums.

In Photos there are no events anymore since iPhoto Events and Albums overlapped in functionality.  There is automatic sorting by Location and Date Information (something like "Automatic Events") and you can still create Albums if you want to collect Photos.